# rails Gem's the Access the GMAIL, Y! Contact Lists via an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Anyone know of any solid GEMs that integrate with the GMAIl and Y! Mail APIs to download a user's contacts (emails)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gmail it's easy: https://rubygems.org/gems/gmail or maybe better for your purpose: https://rubygems.org/gems/gmail_contacts

I'm gonna have another look for yahoo...

EDIT 1:
yahoo is supposed to be part of https://github.com/mislav/contacts but no example given

EDIT 2:
Another way to see the question is to use the opensocial API as mentionned [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/index.html). It could be a worthy generic solution even if resources are a bit scattered.

Comment: Thanks, are these screen scrapers, or using the GMAIL API? Any docs or examples you can show as an example? thxa

Comment: They really use the API, I read your former comments carefully :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You login to gmail using AuthSub mechanism. https://github.com/stuart/google-authsub
2. Try google contacts using some method as :
   http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2008/04/18/import-gmail-contacts-using-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thanks Ved but trying to see if there is a GEM available that wraps this all up given it's such a common feature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe contacts gem: https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts